# Generating random variables from the Cantor Distribution

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, probability-distributions, simulation

I am looking for a method (exact, if possible, but at least asymptotically correct) for generating random variates from a [Cantor Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution)? It seems like its abstract definition prevents this. In essence, can one "invert" the [Cantor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#CITEREFScheeffer1884)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B_j$, $j = 1 \ldots \infty$, are independent Bernoulli(1/2) random variables, then $X = 2 \sum_{j=1}^\infty 3^{-j} B_j$ has a Cantor distribution.
You could let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and take $B_j$ to be the $j$'th base-2 digit of $U$ after the "decimal" point.

Comment: Thanks! So practically speaking, I can get arbitrarily good accuracy with this method depending on where I truncate the infinite series?

Comment: Yes. Notice that it's not different then getting a U[0,1] (or any other continuous) RV.

Comment: Wasn't the question the other way round? However, from a Cantor distribution you can get a Bernoulli sequence which gives you a uniform distribution and hence every distribution on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth this method does not generate U[0,1], it generates a value from the cantor distribution. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: If you agree that you can create a Bernoulli sequence from the Cantor distribution then $U=\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}B_j$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: You could go either way: given $U$, take its base-2 digits and generate $X$ (which is what I intended), or given $X$, take its base-3 digits and generate $U$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks..that's how I interpreted it. You gave the Cantor variate in terms of a binary sequence. Of course, it's well known that the continuous uniform can also be constructed as such, but I didn't see the relevance.